# sbt hanging on process which runs on another computer

Tags: sbt

sbt works fine for one project on this computer but does not even load up (sbt console never returns).  Sbt command works for both projects on another computer.  I have tried running sbt clean but I get the same result. Are there any steps I can take to troublehssot, gather more information and run the sbt console correctly?  Sbt version is 0.13.9

Comment: I tried removing some files from the project directory which helped move the process forward.  Resolving the dependencies is now taking forever but I guess I can wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run sbt after removing Build.scala and plugins.sbt file which were not needed for the project (perhaps I am mistaken in that assumption).  For some reason, without removing the files, the sbt console was not coming up (or was going to take a very long time before coming up).